# Best model for predicting user ranking of a bag of (travel) options without a fixed size

Tags: data-science-model, ranking

I need to predict which flights users's will choose, as a %.  For example a user searches for flights LHR->JFK. There will be a variable set of available options each with a price, number of legs, total transit time, and airline. Given a bag of options (the number of options varies) I need to predict that say
1.BA, $500, 1 leg, 10 hours - 20% will book this
2.AA, $600, 1 leg, 10 hours - 15% will book this
3.EY, $600, 2 legs, 20 hours - 5% will book this
...

I have a history of what users booked from each back. Maybe I need a model which ranks the features, not sure how to set that up. Possibly I can train on every pairwise choice of chosen option vs. each not chosen option.

Preferably I want to do this using Google Cloud Vertex AI AutoML for convenience so I would like to put all the data in one big table and train on that. But not necessarily.  Ideas please? Thanks!